# Translation Angular 2 using ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have all configuration and setting following instructions.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {  Http } from '@angular/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateStaticLoader, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
      deps: [Http]
    })
]
```

**Component:**

```
import {TranslateService,TranslatePipe } from 'ng2-translate';

constructor( private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

  }
```

**And view component:**

```
{{ 'Intro' | translate }}
```

This library does not work for me, it alwsays displays key of word `Intro` instead value translations.

There are not any errors in console. Why `ngx-translate` does not work or what I do wrong.

Comment: Did you create `en.json` file inside `i18n` folder and list `Intro` in that file?

Comment: Exactly. I did all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're still on Angular <4.3, please use Http from @angular/http with http-loader@0.1.0.

so running

```
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader@0.1.0 --save
```

did the trick for me

Source:
[ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code can't really tell what's not working. One difference I noticed is, I did my setup using `HttpLoaderFactory` provided by `ngx-translate` [doc](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#configuration). I'll provide my full setup and you can compare it with your code, if it helps to detect any issues :)

Setup:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

app.module.ts:

```
// i18n library
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [Http]
      }
    })
  ]
```

src > assets > i18n > en.json:

```
{
  "Intro" : "This is intro!"
}
```

component.ts:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class Component{

  constructor(translate: TranslateService){
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
{{ 'Intro' | translate }}
```

Comment: I have the same code, really it does not work, may be I installed another version ?

Comment: Yea, it could be an older version issue. From your `import` statement, it looks like you are using an older version, latest version uses `@ngx-translate` instead of `ng2-translate`. Also, you are not using the `HttpLoaderFactory`, I suggest try using that.

Comment: What is `HttpLoaderFactory` in imports?

Comment: I got this error: `core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: /assets/i18n/en.json`

Comment: Read the answer again. I mentioned it in the answer with a link too. It's the library ngx-translate team tells you to use in the documentation. Also, I added the npm install step for it in the answer too.

Comment: I think problem is in WebPack

Comment: I use Angular Starter

Comment: I think WebPack can not find en.json file

Comment: I use webpack starter too. I didn't need to do any changes for it. The HttpLoader library takes care of finding i18n folder and loading .json files. Also, if webpack couldn't find the file, then it would have been not accessible via your localhost. The setup doc has no additional steps for webpack either. The doc has [this part](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/README.md#aot) for Custom http loader.

Comment: I did in the answer. That's the exact same code I am using and it's working fine for me.