# ngx-translate and angular universal: client side translations not found

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I try without success since a half day to use ngx-translate with the angular universal starter app `https://github.com/angular/universal-starter`. Have someone an idea why following isn't working?

When I start `npm start` my server and reload my pages I see briefly that the translation is found before being replaced with the `key` which traditionally show that something doesn't work with ngx-translate. Also when I change the path of the translation in the `server-app.module.ts` I see an error in the console of the server, therefore I think that my server part is alright and that the problem comes from the client side.

app.module.ts:

```
 export function exportTranslateStaticLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
 }

 imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: exportTranslateStaticLoader,
      deps: [Http]
    }
  }
  )
]
```

browser-app.module.ts:

```
 imports: [TranslateModule.forChild()]
```

server-app.module.ts:

```
  export function translateFactory() {
    return new TranslateUniversalLoader('./dist/assets/i18n', '.json');
  }

  imports: [
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
         loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
           useFactory: translateFactory
      }
    })
 ]
```

TranslateUniversalLoader:

```
 import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
 import {TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
 const fs = require('fs');

 export class TranslateUniversalLoader implements TranslateLoader {
   constructor(private prefix: string = 'i18n', private suffix: string = '.json') {}

   public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
     return Observable.create(observer => {
 observer.next(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${this.prefix}/${lang}${this.suffix}`, 'utf8')));
       observer.complete();
     });
   }
 }
```

webpack.common.js:

```
 plugins: [
new copyWebpackPlugin([
     {
       from: './src/assets/i18n/en.json',
       to: './assets/i18n/en.json'
     }
   ])
 ]
```

app.component.ts:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
     this.translateService.use('en');
 }
```

Futhermore, when I query `http://localhost:8000/assets/i18n/en.json` I get a valid answer back respectively my en.json:

```
{
   "TEST": "Super super"
 }
```

Any help appreciated, this drives me nuts.

Comment: Try a simpler setup as guided in the [doc](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage). You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380000/5556177)

Comment: Thx but I won't try a simpler setup, I want to use ngx-translate in case of angular universal and I don't have anything else in my project except a clone of the universal starter app and ngx-translate

Comment: The simpler setup is for ngx-translate, recommended by the ngx-translate team in their doc. It automatically pulls in the json files from `assets > i18n`, so you don't have to change anything in `webpack.common.js`. End of the day, it's your choice :)

Comment: There, https://gist.github.com/ocombe/8af9d555ab2da45cd1042ef2ccb0ef6b,  the example of @ocombe the creator of ngx-translate displaying the use of TranslateUniversalLoader. Following this my server side, like I said, looks ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, in app.module.ts I should inject HttpClient instead of Http ( the README about AoT still displayed Http):

```
 imports: [
     HttpClientModule,
     TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: exportTranslateStaticLoader,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  }
   )
  ]
```

Comment: with this I get Error: No provider for HttpClient

Comment: @netshark1000 you most probably need to import HttpClientModule in your app.module. HttpClientModule was introduced with Angular 4.3 http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Comment: thanks - it helped to remove the error. But my translations are not found (without any error in console)...

Comment: @netshark1000 you should create a new separate question/post and document your problem (how does your code look, module, app.component, package.json etc.)